# $ is not defined: What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a JS error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

When my page loads up, IE7 notifies me of a run time error. In addition, my Firebug on Firefox warns me of an error:

```
$ is not defined
(?)
[Break on this error] $(document).ready(function() { $("a#sin...Out': 300, 'overlayShow': false }); });
```

When I go to the lines in question its this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/magazeen/js/jquery/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $("a#single_image").fancybox(); $("a#inline").fancybox({ 'hideOnContentClick': false }); $("a.group").fancybox({ 'zoomSpeedIn': 300, 'zoomSpeedOut': 300, 'overlayShow': false }); });
    </script>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may have only included the dropdown part of jQuery, and not the whole thing. Try including just the JQuery.js file, without specification as to what part.

Answer (score 12):

Do you have a script reference to jQuery above the script block in question?  The reason you are seeing this error is because you are using the jQuery function **`$`** without referencing jQuery itself.

You need to add a script reference to jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/yourJsDir/jQuery.js"></script>
```

if you have a local copy of jQuery.js.  Otherwise you can use Google's hosted version like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Just make sure that these script references live above the script block in question as that way your jQuery plugin will have **`$`** defined for it.

Comment: thanks I was having this problem and realized I declared the jsquery after my javascript file in the html.....

Answer (score 4):

Try to include the JQuery js before your custom Js file on html:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/___your js___ .js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your code uses [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). Are you sure you have included the JQuery library in the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include the normal `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permissions issue. Look to make sure that your files have access to that .js file. They should be 777.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem yesterday and it was because I did not have the proper reference to the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a file locally at file:///Users/lo_fye/Desktop/jquery/index.html
I was including the scripts with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

And I was getting the same error:

```
$ is not defined
```

The fix was prepending a period to the script name, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem might also be to security issue.
If you have authentication on your website, for example

```
<authentication mode="Forms">   
<forms loginUrl="file1.aspx" defaultUrl="file2.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/> 
</authorization>
```

Then you must exclude your script folder from this security settings with the following in web.config.

```
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I got this error, it was either because 
1- reference to the jquery.js was wrong ( wrong path) 
2- wrong file name ...

So correct the path or spellings or file names/folder names etc

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```